# how to read password from java class for the data source in apache shiro.ini file

Tags: java, shiro

i want to set the data source password from the java class. so i configure apache shiro.ini file for reading the password field from the java class but its not work.

This is my shiro.ini file for data source

```
     ds = com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource
     ds.serverName = localhost
     ds.user = root

     dbpassword=com.test.password.PasswordFactory   //this is class name
     ds.password=$dbpassword.password
     ds.databaseName = test
     jdbcRealm.dataSource = $ds
```

and the PasswordFactory java class is

```
package com.test.password;

public class PasswordFactory {

public String password; 
public PasswordFactory(){
    password="root";
}   
public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}
public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}
  }
```

this will throwing exception
The object with id [dbpassword.password] has not yet been defined and therefore cannot be referenced.  Please ensure objects are defined in the order in which they should be created and made available for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

You've set dbpassword to be the entire class PasswordFactory, and the factory class itself does not have a variable "password"; instead, only instances of PasswordFactory have a password. You need to construct an instance of PasswordFactory, using shiro to do the equivalent of the java code

```
dbpassword=new com.test.password.PasswordFactory()
```

Comment: this throwing exception
org.apache.shiro.config.ConfigurationException: Unable to instantiate class [new com.test.password.PasswordFactory()] for object named 'dbpassword'.  Please ensure you've specified the fully qualified class name correctly.

Comment: @user2549122 I am not familiar with shiro, and instead wrote equivalent Java code. Search the relevant documentation for how to construct Java objects in shiro, and then feel free to suggest an edit with the correct shiro syntax.